# Render to Cubemap Array

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to generate a cubemap array and save depth values etc. I have confirmed that it is generated correctly by glCheckFramebufferStatus, but when I actually render it, it does not store anything.
The simple code is shown below.

```
// Initialize
glGenTextures(1, &CubeMap);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, CubeMap);

for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + j, 0, GL_RGBA16F, 512, 512, ArrayNum, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
}
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &CubeMapRBO);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, CubeMapRBO);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 512, 512);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);


// Render to CubeMap Array
for(int i = 0; i < ArrayNum; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + j, CubeMap, i);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, CubeMapRBO);
    }
}
```

In the case of a 2D texture array, it seems to use glFramebufferTextureLayer instead of glFramebufferTexture2D, but when I applied this to a cubemap, an error was returned.
If anyone knows anything, please comment.

Comment: Do you want 1 framebuffer with 6 color planes or 6 framebuffers (one for each side of the cube)? Your code is a mix of both.

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this code, from how you're allocating storage for the cubemap array to how you're trying to use it. It's also unclear *exactly* what it is that you're trying to achieve here. Do you want to render to each layer-face of the cubemap array separately, or are you trying to render to all of them in the same drawing command?

Comment: Sorry for lack of knowledge. I'm thinking of rendering all 6 faces in one framebuffer.